# How do you iterate over the elements of an R package?

Tags: r, na

I am searching for a dataset in `datasets` that contains `NA` for some course notes. As a pseudo-Python list comprehension, this is what I am trying to do:

```
[ tuple(package name as string,  package contains NA as boolean) for package in datasets ]
```

How do you iterate over an R package?

Comment: like this? `tmp <- mget(ls('package:datasets'), inherits = TRUE); which(sapply(tmp, anyNA))`

Comment: Do you want to look for `NA` in the entire dataset? How would your expected output look?

Comment: @rawr, this worked beautifully. If you want to change this to an answer then I will be happy to accept it.